# Android - How to open the email client directly

Tags: android, email-client

I want to open the default email client instead of showing the options. I tried but i am not getting please can anyone help me.

I used the following code:

```
  final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        emailIntent.setType("text/html");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My Allergy Journal");       
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml("<small>"+sb.toString()+"</small>"));                                 
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email:"));
```

**It's show the options**

[image]

**But I want to open then Default email client directly.**

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can used the following code to open whatever intent you want eg gmail, facebook, email etc..Simple in the type as used in my code pass "gmail" if you want to open gmail, pass "face" if u want to open facebook

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
intent.setType("text/html");
List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

if (!resInfo.isEmpty())
{
    for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) 
    {
    if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains(type) || info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains(type)) 
    {
            intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, htmlBody);
            intent.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);   
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getResources().getString(R.string.share_send_text)));
        }
}
```

Comment: I want to open android email client. For this what string i used instead of type?

Comment: Hi,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42968587/android-email-client-receiver-email-id-empty-in-android-parse   @AndroidDev can you please check this . thanks

Answer (score 15):

Frame a String in the format `String URI="mailto:?subject=" + subject + "&body=" + body;`

and

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri data = Uri.parse(URI);
intent.setData(data);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will open up the default e-mail program selected by the user.

`Linkify` does it this way. Check out [it's source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/text/util/Linkify.java), if you like.